# What are the DSM requirements for 'Paranoid Personality Disorder'?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, reference-request

What are the requirements for **Paranoid Personality Disorder** as specified by the current revision of the Diagnostic Statistical Manual?

Comment: I realize this _could_ be closed as _"Off topic because it can be answered using commonly-available references"_, but considering it's a $120 dollar book, it's not usually something the average Joe keeps on the shelf, and I would therefore argue against being "commonly available".

Comment: What then do you want to know that's not [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paranoid_personality_disorder#Diagnosis) and not [copyrighted (all rights reserved)](http://www.dsm5.org/Pages/PermissionsPolicy.aspx)?

Comment: @NickStauner I was not aware of their strict copyright adherence; I assumed since it was a diagnostic tool, the information would be more "open", and I just didn't know where to find it.

Comment: @NickStauner I was able to dig up at least some satisfactory information based on the links you provided; thank you. If rep is important to you, you are welcome to create a similar answer; I'll remove mine and accept yours.

Comment: The DSM-V is available in every university library in the US and Europe.

Comment: @what No, you'll not find a DSM-V but you will with the help of a librarian find a DSM 5. Also you need not announce your too whatever to copy and paste from your copy.

Comment: @IQAndreas i answered this question correctly i hope you got to read what the DSM 5 said before it was deleted.

Comment: @caseyr547 Yeah, thanks, I did. I had an inkling it would be deleted, so I saved a copy once I saw you posted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your asking for a very small citation from the DSM 5. I believe it falls under [fair use](https://web.archive.org/web/20210605143659/https://www.copyright.gov/fls/fl102.html). I'd be glad to add this to the internet for scholarship and research with another citations about Cluster A because it makes no changes to the value of DSM-5.

> Paranoid Personality Disorder
>
> Diagnostic Criteria 301.0 (F60.0)
>
> A. A pervasive distrust and suspiciousness of others such that their motives are inter­preted as malevolent, beginning by early adulthood and present in a variety of con­ texts, as indicated by four (or more) of the following:
>
> 1. Suspects, without sufficient basis, that others are exploiting, harming, or deceiving him or her.
> 2. Is preoccupied with unjustified doubts about the loyalty or trustworthiness of friends or associates.
> 3. Is reluctant to confide in others because of unwarranted fear that the information will be used maliciously against him or her.
> 4. Reads hidden demeaning or threatening meanings into benign remarks or events.
> 5. Persistently bears grudges (i.e., is unforgiving of insults, injuries, or slights).
> 6. Perceives attacks on his or her character or reputation that are not apparent to oth­ers and is quick to react angrily or to counterattack.
> 7. Has recurrent suspicions, without justification, regarding fidelity of spouse or sexual partner.
>
> B. Does not occur exclusively during the course of schizophrenia, a bipolar disorder or depressive disorder with psychotic features, or another psychotic disorder and is not attributable to the physiological effects of another medical condition.
>
> Note: If criteria are met prior to the onset of schizophrenia, add “premorbid,” i.e., “paranoid personality disorder (premorbid).”

-DSM-5

A general explanation of DSM Cluster A is as follows:

> Cluster A: Paranoid, Schizoid, and Schizotypal Personality Disorders
>
> Cluster A is called the odd, eccentric cluster. It includes Paranoid Personality Disorder, Schizoid Personality Disorder, and Schizotypal Personality Disorders. The common features of the personality disorders in this cluster are social awkwardness and social withdrawal. These disorders are dominated by distorted thinking.
>
> The Paranoid Personality Disorder* is characterized by a pervasive distrust and suspiciousness of other people. People with this disorder assume that others are out to harm them, take advantage of them, or humiliate them in some way. They put a lot of effort into protecting themselves and keeping their distance from others. They are known to preemptively attack others whom they feel threatened by. They tend to hold grudges, are litigious, and display pathological jealously. Distorted thinking is evident. Their perception of the environment includes reading malevolent intentions into genuinely harmless, innocuous comments or behavior, and dwelling on past slights. For these reasons, they do not confide in others and do not allow themselves to develop close relationships. Their emotional life tends to be dominated by distrust and hostility.

-[DSM-5: The Ten Personality Disorders: Cluster A](https://web.archive.org/web/20150723102435/http://www.sevencounties.org:80/poc/view_doc.php?type=doc&id=479&cn=8)

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, the DSM 5 is under [a very strict copyright](http://www.dsm5.org/Pages/PermissionsPolicy.aspx).

However, there is a list of PPD requirements in the ICD-10 that is publicly available online:

- [ICD-10: F60.0 Paranoid personality disorder](http://apps.who.int/classifications/icd10/browse/2010/en#/F60.0)

That section of the manual describes Paranoid Personality Disorder as follows:

> **F60.0 Paranoid personality disorder**
>
> Personality disorder characterized by excessive sensitivity to setbacks, unforgiveness of insults; suspiciousness and a tendency to distort experience by misconstruing the neutral or friendly actions of others as hostile or contemptuous; recurrent suspicions, without justification, regarding the sexual fidelity of the spouse or sexual partner; and a combative and tenacious sense of personal rights. There may be excessive self-importance, and there is often excessive self-reference.

Comment: Glad you were able to find something. I agree the copyright on the DSM-V is somewhat of a shame. I'd only add what Wikipedia adds: "It is a requirement of ICD-10 that a diagnosis of any specific personality disorder also satisfies a set of [general personality disorder criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personality_disorder#Diagnosis). It is also pointed out that for different cultures it may be necessary to develop specific sets of criteria with regard to social norms, rules and obligations."

Comment: your comment about DSM 5 is wrong

Comment: @caseyr547 How so, what is wrong about it? Do they actually have a copy available online for public reference?

Comment: @IQAndreas in the united states we are allowed something called fair use see my answer for the exact response

Comment: sorry didnt mean to edit your question was editing mine and suddenly your got eddied too.